# Mysql Group by clusters of results in time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DATETIME field in a mysql table with random entries. I would like to select object groups, and break them apart when there is a four hour gap. Ideally I could return all IDs within each group in an array (or sub-group?).

This seems beyond my SQL skills.

Any interesting solutions?

Comment: You're using terms that MySQL doesn't know about

Comment: 'twould be helpful if you could present a small example, with a few table rows and a few desired resultset rows.

Comment: That is as close as I think I am going to go. As i mentioned in the post below, now I am selecting all rows by datetime, and analyzing the time between the records; incrementing group by 1 every time the difference is larger than four hours. The use case means there are between 400 - 1500 records analyzed and the code is executed frequently. It seems like something SQL would have been able to provide (CLUSTER by time where breaks are 4 hours) type of thing... Thanks for the fiddle, it gives me ideas on how to accomplish "almost the same thing", by reducing my function to greatest id/ least id.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is meant to perform set operations on data, while what you're asking for involves sequential processing.

So, I'd suggest processing it sequentially, rather than trying to twist SQL to try to do this.  I believe that you have two basic choices:

1. Select data from the table in a stored procedure, using a cursor to process the results.
2. Execute a select statement from the external, stand-alone language of your choice (Java, C#, Python, PHP...whatever floats your boat), and group the data appropriately there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL `DATE_FORMAT` clause.

**Example**

```
SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d %k:00:00') AS DATETIME) hour
  FROM table
 WHERE date = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 4 HOUR
  GROUP BY CAST(DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d %k:00:00') AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: I was hoping I could accomplish this in SQL, but the SQL select statement does help a little. My current solution is to start at the top and select the previous record, and calculate the time between them. When they are greater than four hours, I increment group = group + 1, into a temporary table. This seems like its not the most efficient way to code this problem, and the code executes very frequently. Thanks for the help... It does kind of give me some ideas about grouping the records, while not ideal serves the same functionality.